# Same Culture, different value conversions

Tags: c#, asp.net, culture

My website extracts data from a text-file into a database. After reading the data, I convert string-values into double, using:

```
oracom.Parameters.Add("nstpreisvm", OracleDbType.Double).Value = Convert.ToDouble(_material.Mat_StPreisVm);
```

If I check the results in the database now, (The column expects the `NUMBER`-format), I get two different values: On my localhost via Visual Studio 2010, the database returns `10,15` - But if I make the process on the webserver, the database only shows `10`. How does this happen?

I implemented a little lable on the website now, filling it with the current culture on the Page-Load:

```
label.Text = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();
```

The `CurrentCulture` is `en-GB` for both instances, so what is the problem here? Am I missing anything?

---

My local windows is Win7 SP1 with a german language-pack, the server is Win2008 R2 with standard English installation.

Comment: What is the type expected by the column where you're storing this value?

Comment: @Aymeric Its a Oracle DB, it expects for this column a `NUMBER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar problem on a customer server where the customer had manually changed the decimal separator symbol for a particular culture on that server. You can check this using:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
```

I would suggest explicitly specifying the decimal separator symbol when you do the parsing:

```
Double.Parse("1,25", new NumberFormatInfo(){ NumberDecimalSeparator = "," });
```

Comment: I will try this out, still in a meeting. But thanks for the answer, I give you feedback later!

Comment: It worked, thanks alot! Never thought that I have to go such a far way just because of parsing a string ...